# Tab Autocomplete "Command Substitution error"

Tags: bash, scripts, gnome-terminal, vim, debugging

I used to never rely on it, but now that I am hooked, this is driving me nutty. When I am in terminal and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete my statement, it works for most commands (cd, mv, rm, etc) but it is broken for vim/vi. When I type `vim` <kbd>Tab</kbd> or anything similar, I get an error as soon as I hit tab:

```
bash: command substitution: line 905: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
bash: command substitution: line 905: `        }'
```

I would try to fix this myself, but I have no idea what file to even look in. I tried `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash-completion`, and it is one of the few files I have found related to the bash with more than 900 lines, but line 905 is dealing with IP addressing. Here it is, for the sake of being thorough:

```
-ne 's|.*inet[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^[:space:]/]*\).*|\1|p' )" \
```

Anyway, I tried installing the latest bash-completion from git, as suggested in [How to fix corrupted bash-completion in command substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164231/how-to-fix-corrupted-bash-completion-in-command-substitution), but it didn't help. Closing and relaunching bash sometimes helps for a few s, and `sudo -i` causes it to work, but of course I don't want to stay logged in as `su` every time I need to edit some stuff. Any idea what file I need to look at to correct this thing?

EDIT: If I run bash inside the terminal, I see no immediate changes (colors remain the same, etc.) but I can <kbd>Tab</kbd> with vim. Of course, all of my aliases are also lost from my previous session, and if I execute a shell script from bash, it returns to the "outer" shell, thus causing the problem to arise again or forcing me to re-bash. It would really make my life easier if I could just fix the script that is malfunctioning here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you’re on the right track Ronald. In you bash_completion file there is a function called _ip_address that has a variable assignment that spans five lines. Try checking yours against all five lines between line numbers 928 and 932 in the bash_completion file at [THIS LINK](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/bash_completion). Spelling counts ;)